# In R how do I convert a character based matrix into a vector?

Tags: r

I have a matrix which looks like:

```
  1         2         3
1 part     of a      text1
2 part     of a      text2
3 part     of a      text3
```

I need a vector from it which lines will be:

`c("part of a text1","part of a text 2","part of a text3"`)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

you can try this

```
apply(df, 1, paste0, collapse=" ")
[1] "part of a text1" "part of a text2" "part of a text3"
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use `do.call(paste` after converting the 'matrix' to `data.frame` as it will be faster for big datasets with >1e6 rows.  Having said that, not every dataset is a big one...

```
 do.call(paste, as.data.frame(m1))
 #[1] "part of a text1" "part of a text2" "part of a text3"
```

If the number of columns are less i.e. 3 as in the example, even manually specifying the columns and using either `sprintf` or `paste` will be very fast.

```
  sprintf('%s %s %s', m1[,1] , m1[,2], m1[,3])
  #[1] "part of a text1" "part of a text2" "part of a text3"
```

#### Benchmarks

```
  m2 <- m1[rep(1:nrow(m1), 1e6),]
  system.time(do.call(paste, as.data.frame(m2)))
  #  user  system elapsed 
  # 2.873   0.000   1.816 

  system.time(apply(m2, 1, paste0, collapse=' '))
  #  user  system elapsed 
  #23.486   0.000  20.441 

  system.time(sprintf('%s %s %s', m2[,1], m2[,2], m2[,3]))
  #  user  system elapsed 
  #1.492   0.000   1.262 

  system.time(paste(m2[,1], m2[,2], m2[,3]))
  #   user  system elapsed 
  # 1.245   0.000   1.051
```

#### data

```
 m1 <- structure(c("part", "part", "part", "of a", "of a", "of a", 
 "text1", 
 "text2", "text3"), .Dim = c(3L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", 
 "2", "3"), c("X1", "X2", "X3")))
```